# End of a time series have to be "corrected" before decomposition if partial period?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have a few times series that are Google search terms which a period of length 1 year with 12 months in each year. As we are in February, the latest data shows only one and a half months.

All my decomposed series show a downward trend at the very end of each graph. Is this a real trend or do I need to apply a correction due to the end of the time series being an incomplete cycle?

See this image (from the beginning of January) where I have a severe dip at the end:
[image]

Would this be an outlier? A change in the trend? Or am I missing a correction value for having just a fraction of the period?

Comment: I believe you will arrive quickly at the correct answer to your question by exploiting the design principle behind this plot: namely, the invariant relation **data = seasonal + trend + remainder** holds at every time point.  Thus, if the trend seem wacky at the end, that *must* be accompanied by some compensating errors in the seasonal or remainder terms.  Do you see any?

Comment: @whuber hmmm I'll have to think on that.

Comment: It's worth paying attention to the relative scales on the four plots: that's what the gray bars at the right are for.  In your case, that dip in the trend (about $-1$ relative to its low about two time units earlier) should be assessed in the context of a seasonal peak-to-trough amplitude of about $25.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some biased opinions for your consideration. To put it into the context, let me first take an excerpt from this great STL tutorial (http://www.gardner.fyi/blog/STL-Part-II/): "`the notional of seasonal variation is always intrinsically ambiguous: whether the temporal variation should be considered Seasonal, Trend, or Remainder is, to a degree, a matter of opinion and determined by choice of model and model parameters. This is true in STL as well as any seasonal variational approach.`" Translated differently, time series decomposition is more of an art than a science; the models/algorithms can't tell whether the results make sense or not and the interpretations need to be informed by domain expertise.

In that tutorial, you can see that, due to the use of Loess, the edge effects from STL are inevitable, but whether the effects matter or not is a judgment call. There is no way to avoid such edge effects unless bringing more data or introducing more model assumptions.

To me, the most straightforward way to determine whether the dip you got is a 'true' signal or a model artifact is to resort to the domain knowledge. If that is not possible, a least thing to do is to test out several alternative algorithms/models and see if consistent patterns are found.

Here is a quick example using a monthly Google search trend time series for the term `beach` to illustrate with three model settings (`STL` and `Rbeast`). `Rbeast` is a Bayesian time series decomposition method where I implemented the BEAST algorithm (if needed, more info about it is available here https://github.com/zhaokg/Rbeast).

```
beach = c(59,56,60,60,67,73,76,69,59,46,43,46,58,58,62,60,67,78,81,69,53,49,49,44,57,56,60,57,64,73,78,67,50,45,43,43,54,56,61,59,65,73,77,67,51,45,41,43,53,54,61,59,
64,73,76,69,47,43,40,44,54,55,60,58,65,71,77,64,51,44,41,42,53,52,58,59,64,76,77,66,50,43,40,42,55,62,66,65,71,83,93,77,57,51,46,50,60,62,65,68,74,87,89,78,57,
49,48,48,54,57,62,63,70,81,91,76,55,48,46,49,58,59,64,65,74,83,91,74,51,47,46,47,55,59,68,64,74,89,95,76,60,49,46,49,56,65,73,71,78,93,100,84,61,57,47,50,56,
61,71,72,75,93,98,80,62,50,45,49,60,63,68,71,73,89,100,78,61,54,46,48,57,61,70,69,73,92,92,76,58,48,46,49,57,59,52,40,70,92,83,72,59,50,42,45,52,62,72,78,82,
93,95,78,61,54,49,51,58,63,69);
beach = ts(beach, start=c(2004,1), frequency=12);

o1 = stl(beach, 'per')
plot(o1)

# Rbeast is a Bayesan time series decomposition method I developed
# It does time series decomposition and changepoint detection at the 
# same time
library(Rbeast)
o2 = beast(beach, season='harmonic') # use a harmonic curve to fit the seasonal component
o3 = beast(beach, season='svd')      # use a svd-based curve to fit the seasonal component
plot(o2)
plot(o3)
```

Here is the result from the `STL` decomposition:
[image: STL result]

Below are the results from the `BEAST` decomposition using the harmonic seasonal and SVD-based seasonal forms, respectively. The BEAST results are quite different from the STL one. The two BEAST results look similar but differ a bit for the end of the time series: This reflects exactly what `whuber` commented about the compensation between the terms: In the harmonic version, the observed anomaly at the end went mainly to the trend component; and in the svd version, it went mainly to the seasonal component. I don't think there is any way to tell which is practically better, which is a problem that can be best addressed with more future data.

[image]

[image]

Rbeast/BEAST also captures some robust patterns that fit the expectation of some "domain" knowledge (i.e., more search popularity expected for hotter weather). Take the detected changepoints/abrupt changes (i.e., those times indicated by the vertical dashed lines in either the seasonal or trend signals) as an example. There was a sudden jump (or structural break) around the summer of 2011 (The summer of 2011 was the hottest one on record for the US: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_North_American_heat_wave#:~:text=Record%20heat,-The%20National%20Climatic&text=Since%201901%2C%20only%20the%20Dust,the%20hottest%20summer%20on%20record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_North_American_heat_wave#:%7E:text=Record%20heat,-The%20National%20Climatic&text=Since%201901%2C%20only%20the%20Dust,the%20hottest%20summer%20on%20record)). There was also an abrupt rise at the start of 2016, again possibly attributed to the abnormally warm temperature (January 2016 Was the Most Abnormally Warm Month Ever Recorded: https://weather.com/news/climate/news/record-warmest-january-global-2016).  There was a sharp drop in the search popularity around April 2020 (attributed apparently to the covid outbreak, supported by our "domain" knowledge, but in our version, the abrupt change was reflected in the seasonal curve and another was more reflected in the trend curve.